# csv Table formatting using Python

Tags: python, datatable

I want to open table and format it from type-I to II. Is there a good package to do such massaging? I don't want to run a loop/etc...

Type-I

[image]

Type-II

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html#getting-started).

The following code creates a "table" as you described. Once created, I'm pivoting the table converts into the Type-II table. I've added additional comments in the code. I hope that helps.

```
import pandas as pd

#create some data
table = {'unit': ['1A1', '1A1', '1B1', '1B1'], 'status': ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Pass']}

#create a Dataframe object where columns names are unit and status
df = pd.DataFrame(data=table, columns=['unit','status'])

print("original table")

#preview the created dataframe
print(df.head())

#remove duplicate entries
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

#pivot table and store in a new object called df2
df2 = df.pivot(index='unit', columns='status', values=['status']).fillna('Not Available')

print("Transformed table")

#print top n rows
print(df2.head())
```

You can checkout a mini demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/OverdueLightcoralAbandonware)